# C/C++ how to isolate libraries for unit tests? - in example Mbed

Tags: c++, c, unit-testing, tdd

I created a simple mbed project and exported it as makefile project. From that point, I developed my application. Whenever I need something from mbed, i just include mbed.h file, and I have access to all nice objects like digitalOut, Timeout, etc.

When I wanted to create a test for a module, I realized, that `#include "mbed.h"` was very annoying. 
I wanted to stub all those nice objects in the test anyway, but the errors just keep paling up, and I could not make the test to compile.

To overcome that issue I created proxy objects for the things that I use in  my project, and I can swap their implementation by simple `#if Test` in the implementation, if the macro was not satisfied, I included mbed.h, and pass the parameters and result to it, but when it was satisfied, I did dummy implementation, which I could override by a stub in the test. In this approach I do not have to deal with `#include "mbed.h"` in tests, but I get a feeling, that it should not be necessary, and it is just another unnecessary level of abstraction.

I would like to ask How to make good stubs and Tests when I use Mbed, (or any other library - I want to test MY code, not the code of external library in unit tests) I thought that isolating libraries for tests, should be easy, but I'm stuck with this for a while, and I do not know how to do it the right way.

Let me give you a simple example what do I mean:

```
#include "mbed.h"

class A{
mbed::DigitalOut& pin;
  public:
    A(mbed::DigitalOut& p):pin(p){}
    void toggle(){
        pin = ~pin;
    }
};
```

In this simple case, I use DigitalOut from mbed. To make it work I think that I should provide stub for the `operator int()` and `operator=(int)`, because those are only functions that I used.

In fact It is not enough to compile a simple test because, under `#inclued "mbed.h"` there are many more objects, that need to be satisfied to link the binary. Is there any way to stub all those objects with dummy implementation, and link that to the test? - I Could then overwrite those implementations by google mock and use them in tests.

How should look like a stub file and test file for such a simple example? To be able to run the tests on x86

Comment: The approaches usable in C and C++ would be wildly different, I guess.

Comment: Could you elaborate?, I use C++, but I thought that in C there would be the same issue with unsatisfied implementation when compiling test of modules that include external library, library which I can not or do not want to compile with the test

Comment: C has no overloading or classes/namespaces (!)

Comment: There are ports of xUnit/CppUTest for a particular platform and toolchain (stm32/armcc etc) cross-compiler, but SO isn't really the place to ask for library recommendations.

Comment: Sorry if this comments sounds silly, but I'm not using mbed. If the *real* implementations are in a library you could provide your *stub* or *mock* implementations as separate modules. If you add this modules when linking your tests, the linker should resolve references to them. There will be no need for a source code change in your tested module.